# Add a string to each date in an array

Tags: php, string, date, utc

This is a simple questions. I do not know i'm not able to achieve this. How to add a string(Date.UTC) to each date in the row using php like show below

```
[Date.UTC(2011,11,20),5],[Date.UTC(2011,11,21),5]
```

As of now i have my result like this, just need to add Date.UTC string to each date in the row.

```
[["2011,09,03","1"],["2011,09,06","53"]]
```

Comment: How is this MySQL related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you have seems to be a valid json string so...

```
$json = '[["2011,09,03","1"],["2011,09,06","53"]]' ;
$dates = json_decode($json, true);

var_dump($dates);

foreach($dates as &$date){
    $date[0] = "Date.UTC({$date[0]})" ;
}

var_dump($dates);
//Pack back to json if you need $json = json_encode($dates);
```

Comment: My result doesn't have just 2 dates.. there n number of dates. I've used json encode to store the result.

Comment: So? I just provided a perfect solution for you. All you have to do is to assign your data to variable `$json`.

Comment: @jari..Thank you so much for your help!  I got this solved, this is what i wrote in my code$date = "Date.UTC(".$row ['date'].")"